# How can I use WASP permanently without re-installing?

Tags: windows, powershell, wasp

I'm writing powershell queries using WASP.

But every time I want to use WASP I have to do :

> c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>**powershell.exe Install.ps1 -Force**

Then I get this result :

[image]

And as they say : I run this in Powershell_ise.exe :

`Add-PSSnapin WASP`

Now -  I can write queries using WASP.

**Question**

The **next** time I start Powershell_ise.exe and try to invoke the script :

I get this error :

[image]

- I don't want to install it every time in order to use WASP.   What can I do in order for Powershell_ise.exe to recognize WASP automatically  ?

NB

Maybe the answer is in the last console result line :
*You can also add that line to your Profile script to load it automatically.*

But I didn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `import-module` in your profile and you can look at your profile file using `$profile` var :

```
$profile.AllUsersAllHosts
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1

$profile.AllUsersCurrentHost
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1

$profile.CurrentUserAllHosts
C:\Users\JPB\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1

$profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost
C:\Users\JPB\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok found it :

This article says it all : http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/04/understanding-and-using-powershell-profiles.aspx

When running this : `$PROFILE | Format-List * -Force`

we get : 
PS C:\Users\royin> $PROFILE | Format-List * -Force

```
AllUsersAllHosts       : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
AllUsersCurrentHost    : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
CurrentUserAllHosts    : C:\Users\royin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
CurrentUserCurrentHost : C:\Users\royin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
Length                 : 78
```

so just add a file named `profile.ps1` to the library ^ (choose)

And write `Add-PSSnapin WASP` inside that file.